# notepad++ find php resource in project

Tags: php, notepad++

Is there a way (plugin?) for notepad++ to find a php resource in a complex project? 
When I work in a project I can load the complete thing through the project window, fine. But when I have a file.php where there is a reference call for example

```
$this->param...
```

I would like to know what $this references, but if the class is defined in another file2.php, and both are called from a third file3.php I end up searching for ever. Any suggestions, or maybe an alternative if not possible in notepad++?

Comment: Notepad++ is a text editor, not an IDE. I would be truly amazed if someone wrote a plugin that actually worked as a full PHP parser and soft-runner that keeps track of which variable reference points to which (absolutely dynamic) object. Have you considered using something more suited to full project delevopment like PHP Storm or even Eclipse with PHP perspective?

Comment: What you need is netbeans, not notepad++. Notepad++ is for single file editing ( and for a lot of other things inluding ftp files, bigggg sql files etc)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can search for the `param` name (When searching, you can select to search trough all project or all opened files) ?

Also, you can use TagsJump plugin to jump to a definition. Install it by using PluginManager.
Another usefull plugin in [SourceCookifier](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/).

But as Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans said, notepadd++ is not an IDE and what you are asking is not possible.

Comment: I used SourceCookifier in project with an obscure language that no ide supported. It is based on ctags and you can define a new language.

The experience was almost like an ide. I could jump to functions, variables, etc. in the current file. It didnot work well with "here is a tag, if it is from a file not opened: open it". 
If I remember correctly it had a "session mode", where you could define a set of files that it would consider for openning and jumping. But I used it exclusively in the current file.